# Java data structure for replacing two maps Map<A,B>, Map<B,C> linked via B value

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a simple caching system in Java that maps an object id (`Integer`) with a timestamp (`Long`) and the latter to a `List<Object>`. I map this situation with two maps:

```
Map<Integer, Long> objectTimestamps = ...
Map<Long, List<Object>> timestampToList = .... //I know, Here I can use something like a Guava's MultiMap, but it is not really important at this point
```

I studied a lot of the collections from libraries like Guava, but I didn't found any specific data structure to be used in this case. Can you propose another way to hold this data? Please, consider that I read/insert this values continuously in my algorithm.

PS: In my example I map the timestamp to a list of `Object` instances, but sometimes I map the timestamp to just a simple `Object`.

Comment: you should make an object for keeping your timestamp and list of objects thats it. This is what @Jean Logeart answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply do:

```
public class TimestampObjects {
    private long timestamp;
    private List<Object> objects;
    // + constructors, getters, setters
}
```

And the map would become: `Map<Integer, TimestampObjects>`

Comment: Yes, probably this is a good solution! I should use generics of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html).

The map will be: `Map<Integer, Pair<Long, List<Object>>`.

To add something in the map, you simply do the following:

```
map.put(integerValue, Pair.of(longValue, objectList));
```

Comment: Apache Pair, not Pairs :)

Comment: Honestly I would not introduce a new dependency just for a Pair class :) I will implement a pair by myself